# Google CSE 400 Error

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I'm having an issue getting a client's site to return a valid response from a Google CSE request. I've excluded the 'start' and 'num' values completely and am pasting the url directly into the browser, so there's definitely an issue with my parameters. Here is the url, minus the key, with the added start and num values:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=THIS_IS_MY_KEY&cx=THIS_IS_MY_CSE&q=ANY_QUERY&gl=us&start=1&num=10

No matter what I do with the start and num values, I get the same 400 'Invalid value'. The only thing I can imagine could be wrong is possibly something with the CSE value. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely with your key(API_KEY) or cx(SEARCH_ENGINE_ID) params.
Please have a recheck for any typos etc.

I have just tried with the same(puting my cse id and api keys) and it works fine.

Comment: Same problem here. I use:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=KEY&cx=MY_CX&q=ANY_QUERY&gl=us&start=1&num=10